# Get highest value using partition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the highest spend and show the vendor that has the highest spend in the category . Here is what i have:

```
Vendor    Category   Spend
3M         cat1       200
XX         cat6       150
Bos        cat1       700
JJ         cat0       500
KLM        cat0       100       
XX         cat0       400
```

This is the desired results:

```
Vendor    Category   Spend
XX         cat6       150
Bos        cat1       700
JJ         cat0       500
```

i am not getting the right results

```
select vendor, category, sum(spend) ,row_number() over(partition by vendor order by spend desc) as roworder
from myTable
group by vendor, category
```

Comment: This has been asked so many times. Gordon has a literally identical answer on one of those that has been highlighted as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery to *filter* the data:

```
select t.*
from myTable t
where t.spend = (select max(t2.spend)
                 from myTable t2
                 where t2.category = t.category
                );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by spend desc) as seqnum
      from myTable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Use `rank()` if you want ties in the event of duplicate max values.

Comment: Gordon, i need to sum the spend because sometimes there are multiple vendor and categories with the same vendor names and categories but different spend so i need to always sum the spend

Comment: You don't "SUM" `spend` in your expected results, @moe . The value is `700` for `cat1` for example, not `900`.

Comment: this was just a sample data but in my real data i have where vendor and category are the same but with different spend.  sorry i was trying simplify the sample data

Comment: If your sample data isn't representative of the problem @moe then you aren't going to get representative answers. I suggest posting a new question (possibly deleting this one) with a more informative sample set and results.